# Enemy Detection Distance

Tags: c#, xna

I currently have the movement of my enemy working where they start to move towards the enemy but I am looking to change that to only moving towards the player if the player gets within a certain distance of the enemy so I will need to create some code to work out where the enemy is and if they are within say 175 pixels, the enemy will start to move. I am not sure how to implement this into the code I already have.

**This is my enemy class code for movement:** it uses trig to calculate the shortest distance to the enemy then pushes the enemy object towards the player. Once a collision has occurred, the player is removed.

```
class Enemy : Obj
{
    float spd = 1;
    float detectionDistance = 175;

    public Enemy(Vector2 pos)
        : base(pos)
    {
        position = pos;
        spriteName = "BlackBall";
        speed = spd;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        rotation = point_direction(position.X, position.Y, Player.player.position.X, Player.player.position.Y);
        speed = spd;

        base.Update();
    }

    public override void pushTo(float pix, float dir)
    {
        float newX = (float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        float newY = (float)Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        newX *= pix;
        newY *= pix;
        if (!Collision(new Vector2(newX, newY), new Player(Vector2.Zero)))
        {
            base.pushTo(pix, dir);
        }
    }

    //Uses Trig to calculate the shortest distance to the player then moves towards that position
    private float point_direction(float x, float y, float x2, float y2)
    {
        float diffx = x - x2;
        float diffy = y - y2;
        float adj = diffx;
        float opp = diffy;
        float tan = opp / adj;
        float res = MathHelper.ToDegrees((float)Math.Atan2(opp, adj));
        res = (res - 180) % 360;
        if (res < 0) { res += 360; }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public override void Update()
{
    rotation = point_direction(position.X, position.Y, Player.player.position.X, Player.player.position.Y);
    distance = sqrt(xdiff^2 + ydiff^2) <-- This line is pseudo-code
    if(distance<detectionDistance)
    {
        speed = spd;
    } 
    else
    {
        speed = 0
    }

    base.Update();
}
```

Comment: a bit more context to your answer would be nice. Do I need to replace a line, do I add this to I line? what do I do with it

Comment: I can't really give you any more context without seeing the rest of your code. You need to check if the distance is less than 175 (to follow your example), and if so, move the enemy, if not, do not move the enemy. Not quite sure what the question is to be honest.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you my enemy class and all its code. I am looking to move the enemy towards the play only if the player is within 175 pixels of the enemy

Comment: A few problems with what you have given me. 1. distance doesn't exist in current context. 2. sqrt doesn't exist in current context and 3. xdiff and ydiff don't exist in the current context

Comment: Ya, that line is kinda pseudo-code right now. You're a smart guy, I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming so a bit more help would be necessary

Comment: Well, you'll have to declare the distance variable and the xdiff and ydiff variables, and then calculate the values for xdiff and ydiff. You'll also have to find a function that calculates a square root (try the Math library). Oh, and also for the exponents you can use Math.Pow()

Answer (score 0):

Use the distance formula and check  if the player position is within 175 units.

```
public override void Update()
{
    rotation = point_direction(position.X, position.Y, Player.player.position.X, Player.player.position.Y);
    speed = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(Player.player.position.X - position.X), 2.0) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(Player.player.position.Y - position.Y), 2.0))) <= 175 ? spd : 0;

    base.Update();
}
```

Comment: Inputting that line into my program gives me the error "Operator '^' cannot  be applied to operands of type float and float

Comment: My bad, You have to use Math.Pow. I will fix it. I will warn you that Math.Pow will be slightly slower than using the power operator, as it has to operate on floating point. If you are worried about performance, you may want to cast to int (truncate) and use ^.

Comment: I was thinking about this more and realized that trying to make a circle is going to be fairly intensive. Treating it as a square might be easier and still go unnoticed by the user: `speed = math.Abs(Player.player.position.X - position.X) < 175 && math.Abs(Player.player.position.Y - position.Y) < 175 ? spd : 0;`